# Why do some devs use mod tests for tests?

Tags: rust

Some people do

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
   //all tests here
}
```

While simply putting every test in the end of the file like

```
#[test]
fn test1() {

}

#[test]
fn test2() {

}
```

works too and I can even run single tests by cargo.

What is the difference? Why do some people do it the first way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You often need to share some code between your tests, for example macros and functions used for building the test cases or to check the result values. And you sometimes have to import whole crates just for your tests.

The `#[cfg(test)]` [conditional compilation attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#the-tests-module-and-cfgtest) makes it possible to have code not compiled when not testing. This enables faster checks and a faster compilation in the general case. If you include a crate just for the tests, you can import it in those mods and specify the [dev dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/testing/dev_dependencies.html) in a `[dev-dependencies]` section of your Cargo.toml.

Here's an example of such a test mod where some functions are used in several tests: [wrap.rs](https://github.com/Canop/termimad/blob/master/src/wrap.rs#L184).

I personally create a mod as soon as the tests of a function aren't trivial, even when there's not (yet) any shared help function: the test mod then appears as an easy to notice test block in my code.

Sometimes you go even further by using the "tests" directory solution for your [integration tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests), which makes it easier to have whole mods shared between your tests. This is often the most practical solution when your tests are more than unit tests (some crates have more tests than tested code).

Read [the rust book on test organization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html) to know more.

Comment: Hi Denys, just wanted to give some constructive feedback: Many of the points you make are moot, because `#[test]` is enough to make compilation conditional on `#[cfg(test)]`.

Comment: @Enselic I think you didn't understand: if you need to share code (functions, macros) between tests, you must put it somewhere. And you can avoid compiling this shared code by putting it behind a `#[cfg(test)]`.

Comment: Correct, I missed that point, thanks for clarifying, and sorry for giving unhelpful feedback.

Comment: @Enselic No problem. You made me realizing one thing while looking at examples: shared code in tests is quite rare. There's more to it than just sharing. There's also the idea that such organization seems easier to read with non trivial tests.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want your code under test to be able to access any test code. By putting the tests and helper functions in a child module (and not making them `pub`), you prevent the code under test to access any test code.

The following sample code will help demonstrate my point:

**src/add.rs**

```rust
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

pub fn compiler_test() {
    // Uh oh, below compiles!
    #[cfg(test)]
    test_add();

    // Good, error[E0603]: function `test_add` is private
    #[cfg(test)]
    tests::test_add();
    //     ^^^^^^^^ private function
}

#[test]
fn test_add() {
    assert_eq!(add(4, 5), 9)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_add() {
        assert_eq!(super::add(1, 2), 3)
    }
}
```

Note that skipping `mod tests` does not prevent you from making use of `[dev-dependencies]`, because `#[test]` is enough to make compilation conditional on `#[cfg(test)]`.

Comment: This simple case doesn't demonstrate the reason to use `#[cfg(test)]`: sharing code used in tests (and only in tests).

Comment: Helper functions are not part of my sample code, but above the code I do explicitly make the point of keeping helper functions out of reach to the code under test by using a tests module.